# React Native evaluating 'dataSource.rowIdentities

Tags: react-native

I'm making a basic ListView with dataSource in React-Native, with data that I fetch.

```
class Movies extends Component {
  render() {
    if (this.state.dataSource.getRowCount() === 0) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>
            loading....
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
    else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

  constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
            rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
          }),
        };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData(){
    fetch(HOT_MOVIES_URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        if (responseData) {
          this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData),
          });
        }
      })
      .done();
  }
}
```

yet, I get a

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'dataSource.rowIdentities')

error, tried many ways is also not work contain this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336725/react-native-clonewithrows-error-object-undefined), Any ideas?

Comment: Was your issue that your opening `ListView` tag had no attributes, because `dataSource` and `renderRow` were _after_ the `>` character instead of _before_ it?

Comment: It looks like your problem here was that you were checking if `this.state.dataSource.getRowCount() === 0` but that if statement wouldn't run if the list was undefined or null due to the `===`. It means the else block would run with an empty list and detonate with that error message.

Comment: @tscizzle : Thanks alottttttttttttttttttt

Answer (score 8):

Try setting up the ListView DataSource as a reusable variable, then reusing it whenever you need it. Also, you may be needing to set the dataSource as an empty array until your data comes in. Try something like this:

```
var ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2 })

class Movies extends Component {
  render() {
    if (this.state.dataSource.getRowCount() === 0) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>
            loading....
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
    else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
  constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([]),
        };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData(){
    fetch(HOT_MOVIES_URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        if (responseData) {
          this.setState({
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseData),
          });
        }
      })
      .done();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  I found a solution following code `<ListView  dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)} > </ListView>`

Comment: Is it normal to have the error: undefined is not an object evaluating this.renderRow.bind ?

Comment: Do you have a renderRow method defined?

Comment: No, just like in your sample code. I was thinking that renderRow was a native function. Can you provie a sample of the renderRow method?

Comment: Yeah, you could do one of the following:
1. Have the renderRow inline as a prop to the ListView
`ListView
  dataSource={somedatasource}
  renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>} />`
or 
`<ListView
  dataSource={someDataSource}
  renderRow={this.renderRow} />`
and then
`renderRow(rowData) {
  return <Text>{rowData}</Text>
}`

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be caused by trying to render `ListView` with a falsy list.

I just opened an app I hadn't used in like 6 months and it exploded fantastically because the database was wiped and this `ListView` was trying to render and getting an empty list from Redux `mapStateToProps`.

Long debug story short, I put an empty list check in the render method:

```
render() {
  if (!this.props.employees.length) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>NO EMPLOYEES TO LIST</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
  return (
    <ListView
      enableEmptySections
      dataSource={this.dataSource}
      renderRow={this.renderRow}
    />
  )
}
```

If you somehow keep getting it after that, put a falsy check in `renderRow`.